# Retrieving data from http.get response in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, response

How can I get this 'couponId' from the response data in javascript. I tried response.data.data in an alert but it gives object[object]. I want to store this 'couponId' in a var. I successfully get others like this just fine.. response.data.success and response.data.error_description

```
{"success":"yes","data":{"couponId":"31"},"error_code":"","error_description":""}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get couponId by using 
data.data.couponId

Comment: Welcome :) @Tidya

Answer (score 0):

Try using **response.data.couponId**.